# Do you need a privacy policy and terms/conditions for your android app?

Tags: android, google-play

My app's operates on a simple couple of button clicks. However, as I am gearing up to release it, I couldn't help but notice nearly all the apps have at least a privacy policy and terms/conditions on there page. Is it legally necessary to have both? Or is it just good practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need terms/conditions. Privacy policy are usually required, but that is depending on where you're going to release your app. For example in Europe and California you are required to have a certain type of privacy policy, that include certain specific elements.

"A Terms and Conditions is not required and it’s not mandatory by law. Unlike Privacy Policies, which are required by laws such as the GDPR, CalOPPA and many others, there’s no law or regulation on Terms and Conditions."
- https://www.termsfeed.com/blog/sample-terms-and-conditions-template/#Download_Terms_and_Conditions_Template

After some research I found that Shopify had decent templates: https://www.shopify.com/tools/policy-generator

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to publish an app Google requires you to have privacy policy that you will link to the app so consumers see the privacy policy if they want to. You won't be able to publish without that providing a working link. The terms and conditions is not required by Google.

Comment: is this privacy policy the same as the EU User Consent Policy which is obtained with the User Messaging Platform SDK?